# Casting a struct to another

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm trying to cast a `struct` to another one. But I keep getting this error while compiling:

> conversion to non-scalar type requested

I get the error for this line:

p is a struct prefix and i need to cast it to struct prefix_ipv4

```
 get_info (type, (struct prefix_ipv4) p);
```

Code:

```
ospf_external_info_delete (u_char type, struct prefix_ipv4 p)
{
///////////////
}

struct prefix_ipv4
{
  u_char family;
  u_char prefixlen;
  struct in_addr prefix __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
}

struct prefix
{
  u_char family;
  u_char prefixlen;
  union 
  {
    u_char prefix;
    struct in_addr prefix4;

    struct in6_addr prefix6;

    struct 
    {
      struct in_addr id;
      struct in_addr adv_router;
    } lp;
    u_char val[8];
  } u __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
};
```

Can anyone say why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't cast to a different structure type. You can however **cast to pointer to a different structure type**, and this is widely done with structures that have common starting fields (the way yours do). You could change your function to take a pointer:

```
void get_info(..., struct prefix_ipv4 *prefix)
...
```

And then call it:

```
get_info(type, (struct prefix_ipv4 *)&p);
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot cast one struct type to another, even with an explicit cast. (Insert boilerplate flinching about implicit casting constructors and cast operator overloading.) You can cast a struct pointer to a different struct pointer, which is probably what you should be doing here; incidentally, you should also be passing your struct to the function by pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the C '[union](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/unions.html)' keyword. It allows you to give alternative declarations for the same piece of memory.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is probably a pointer and the error says you cannot cast a pointer to a structure type. If the argument to `ospf_external_info_delete` was a pointer instead, then you can cast a type pointer to another type pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have so little data you should just initialise a `struct prefix_ipv4` from `struct prefix` and pass that.

Or go with the pointer answer, but in the case that the function prototype is easily modified without repercussions I'd be replacing `struct prefix_ipv4` with `struct prefix` as I don't see the need for the ipv4 version which the ipv6 version can handle.